# android touch within triangle

Tags: android, touch

Right, so, my I'm attempting to write a 2d RPG game for Android.  Right now, I simply want to get the mechanics of the world right before attempting to go on to the rest of it so I have no other UI than the screen itself which is the full screen of an HP Touchpad.  I want to split up the screen on the diagonals.  This creates four triangles; one for each direction of travel.  I know how to check to see if a rectangle has been clicked inside but not a triangle.  I have the following code snippet, however:

```
int s = event.y * ggWidth / ggHeight;
int code = (event.x > s) + 2 * (event.x > ggWidth - s);
```

Code should be set to 0-3 based on whichever area within the rectangle of the screen was touched.  However, when I use it, my IDE [AIDE] complains "The '*' operator cannot be applied to instances of type 'int' and 'boolean'."

I don't know if this code is right but it looks like it should work, doesn't it?  Any help getting this code to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(event.x > s)` and `(event.x > ggWidth - s)` returns `boolean`, and you cannot do arithmetic manipulation to it.

Edit: probably, what you want is:

```
int code = (event.x > s ? 1 : 0) + 2 * (event.x > ggWidth - s ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had been trying to figure that out for a while.  Your answer is amazing.